# How can you generate a JSON compilation database using the CLI?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clangpowertools

As described [here](https://clangpowertools.com/blog/generate-json-compilation-database.html) one can generate a JSON compilation database using the UI of Visual Studio. Is it possible to do this in the CLI?

(The use case for this is to use the database with clangd to provide autocompletion to another editor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is a [powershell script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Caphyon/clang-power-tools/master/ClangPowerTools/ClangPowerToolsShared/Tooling/v1/clang-build.ps1) that can be used like this:

```sh
clang-build -export-jsondb
```

If this generates a `compile_commands.json` file in the current directory of the projects in current directory.